# Polymer binding tap to an object method

Tags: javascript, templates, events, bind, polymer

I'm trying to bind a method to an on-tap attribute of a paper-button. After much testing, I've found that I can only bind a (for lack of a better word) top-level function, and not a method of an object in the template.

For example, I have a template, to which I have bound a number of objects, one of which is a user object. Object user has a bunch of methods and variables, like 'isNew' or 'reputation'. The user object also has a method 'addReputation'

I can use the object variables like this :

```
       <template if = '{{user.new}}'><h1>{{user.name}}</h1></template>
```

And I can bind button taps like this:

```
      <paper-button on-tap='{{addReputation}}'>Add Rep</paper-button>
```

But not like this:

```
      <paper-button on-tap='{{user.addReputation}}'>Add Rep</paper-button>
```

Does anyone know why this may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set the method to a handler on your element's prototype it works. That way you can still keep things dynamic:

```html
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.js"></script>

<polymer-element name="my-element" on-tap="{{tapHandler}}">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    click me
    <content></content>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      created: function() {
       this.user = {
         method: function() {
           alert('hi');
          }
        };
        this.tapHandler = this.user.method;
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<my-element></my-element>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped, and solved my problem - but could you (or anyone) help me understand why this is the case? The reason I say this is because I have a 'rightClickMenu' element that I've created, and to run it, I have a method 'show' which takes in an array of functions. I'd like to bind those functions directly to the tap event, but instead I have to write a handler, and use the target.templateInstance.model to get the action I want to call.

Answer (score 0):

i'm sharing my plunk to resolve above problem. [plunk link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xwlxdd?p=preview)

In the template

```
<button on-tap="{{fncall}}" data-fnname="b">b call</button>
```

In the script

```
x.fncall = function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    var fnName = target.getAttribute("data-fnname");
    return x.datamodel[fnName]();
}

Polymer(x);
```